# Array length in Perl

Tags: arrays, performance, perl

Are the following two statements the same internally? 
Will their performance be the same for large arrays?

```
my $Count=scalar @Array; #1
my $Count=0; foreach (@Array) { $Count++;} # 2
```

Comment: An array evaluated in scalar context will return its size, making the `scalar` keyword unnecessary.

Comment: Compare `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E 'my @Array = (4,3,2,1);my $Count=scalar @Array;'` and `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E 'my @Array = (4,3,2,1);my $Count=0; foreach (@Array) { $Count++;}'`

Comment: If you ever want to know whether X performs better than Y in Perl, use [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html).

Comment: @RichardSimões: True, but I personally like to use `scalar @array` just because it's more explicit. (I do not claim to be consistent in such matters.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are radically different. Perl knows the size of an array, so the first is a simple operation (it doesn't need to loop through the array to determine its size).

Answer (score 8):

Please don't worry about "fastest" without having first done some sort of measurement that it matters.

Rather than worrying about fastest, think about which way is clearest.

The specific answer to your question, however, is that the `for` loop will be far far slower because it is calculating a value that Perl already knows.